# How to configure the Marvell 8897 pcie as an access point?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I am trying to configure marvell 8897 pcie as an access point but encountering problems. I have already installed the required driver and firmware: `cfg80211.ko`, `mlan.ko`, `fw_name=` `pcie8897_wlan.bin`, `pcie8897.ko`. I have also installd `dnsmasq` which is not really required but I did it accidentally. Then, I have removed dnsmasq completely. Whenever I want to start my BSS using this command `./uaputl.exe bss_start` an error is showing something like this:

```
File opening Error
Parsing of domain configuration file failed 
Err: Wrong system configuration.
```

I am new to Linux and I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I am sorry that I am using 14.04.1 Thats why I have added a tag 14.04 . But I am very much new in linux and also in configuring the wlan or access point. I am not sure, whose should I tag. Accutually, we have a test system and currently, we are testing the Marvell 8897 pcie chipset for accesspoint . It works perfectly as a client but not for access point and I tried to follow  the link http://blog.csdn.net/ic_soc_arm_robin/article/details/8262492 . whick makes the situation more worse.Thanks in advance. @Zanna

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I'm afraid I don't know how to answer your question, but hopefully others will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some version of the `uaputl` binary (like the one bundled with Steam Link) loads domain configuration file from a relative path `config/80211d_domain.conf`. Missing of this file from current directory causes the utility to exit with error.

The file `80211d_domain.conf` required can be extracted from package distributions of `uaputl`. Note that the current version (1.12) on [GitHub](https://github.com/virt2real/uaputl) loads the file from an absolute path `/usr/share/uaputl/80211d_domain.conf`.